# How to expand a child on clicking a particular item from parent in a list?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[image]

I want to expand/collapse the child View only upon clicking on particular Text view/button like shown in the image.

Comment: why don't you use expandable list view?

Comment: try this: https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: I'm facing issues with selection of check box and I want to expand upon clicking View/Close button from parent.

Comment: set `OnGroupClickListener()` to check box

Comment: I want expand the child item only on particular item as per the requirement not on the entire cell item.OnGroupClickListener() for entire row item click.Clicking on a check box nothing shud happen other than selecting it

Comment: @Tej...I want particular item to be clicked..,I tried using expandable list view but I don't know how to perform action on particular item in expandable...it works only with GroupClick

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`ExpandableRecyclerView`**.

By including your GroupViewHolder and ChildViewHolder in the definition of the class, you'll see that the onCreateGroupViewHolder and onCreateChildViewHolder methods return the correct type :+1:

```
public class GenreAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<GenreViewHolder, ArtistViewHolder> {

  public GenreAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
    super(groups);
  }

  @Override
  public GenreViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_genre, parent, false);
    return new GenreViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public ArtistViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_artist, parent, false);
    return new ArtistViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindChildViewHolder(ArtistViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group,
      int childIndex) {
    final Artist artist = ((Artist) group).getItems().get(childIndex);
    holder.setArtistName(artist.getName());
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindGroupViewHolder(GenreViewHolder holder, int flatPosition,
      ExpandableGroup group) {
    holder.setGenreTitle(group);
  }
}
```

Please checkout the following GitHub repository for complete guide to how can it implement,

[ExpandableRecyclerView](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)

You get the result look like below screenshot,

[image]